# Calculating moments of negative binomial distribution by recurrence relation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The probability mass function of the negative binomial distribution is given like below.

$P(X=x)= {{r+x-1}\choose{x}}p^r(1-p)^x$ ($x\ge0, 0<p<1$)

Let $g(x)$ be a function where $E(g(x))$ and $g(-1)$ is well-defined. Now using the fact that $E((1-p)g(X)) = E(\frac{X}{r+X-1}g(X-1))$, I have to calculate the moments $E(X^3), E(X^4)$.

I've tried $g(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$, but those choices of $g(x)$ needed extra calculation. Am I doing something wrong, or is there an elegant way to calculate those moments using the recurrence relation? Any help is appreciated!